# How to make Kivy app stay in the Task Bar on close

Tags: python, kivy

How to make the Kivy app stay in the Task Bar on close and how to add a list to manage it as I showed in the following pictures,
Can anyone please show me where is that documented or I can read about it?

here is an example:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem some time ago making a tray music app and how i did it was like this:

- Install pystray with pip: `pip install pystray`
- Import both `pystray` and `threading`

As soon as the app starts, i.e inside the on_start function of your app class, use pystray to make a tray icon:

```
def on_start(self):
    image = Image.open("icon.ico")
    icon = pystray.Icon(name="IconName", icon=image, title="YourApp", menu= (
        pystray.MenuItem('Show', default=True, action=lambda: self.show_app()),
        pystray.MenuItem("Quit", action=lambda: self.close_app(icon)),
    ))
    threading.Thread(target=self.run_icon, args=(icon,)).start()

def run_icon(self, icon):
    icon.run()

@mainthread
def close_app(self, icon):
    self.root_window.close()
    icon.stop()

@mainthread
def show_app(self):
    self.root_window.show()
```

You should also make a custom title bar that has a close button, Which hides the window instead of closing the app like your default title bar, like an icon button that calls this function:

```
def end(self):
    self.root_window.hide()
```